# SQL "not like" versus exclusionary subquery

Tags: sql, performance

I simply would like to know if there are benefits going one way or another for the following scenario:

I have a SQL query with many "WHERE" items, like so:

```
Select
*
from
a_table
WHERE
(W like X) AND
(Y like Z) AND
(A not like B) AND
(C not like D)
```

The thing is, I'm wondering for the "Not-like" portion if it would be faster/more efficient as an 'exclusionary subquery', by which I mean I do a select FOR those things instead of cutting those out, and then at the bottom of my query throw in something to the tune of:

```
AND someId NOT IN
(select distinct someId
FROM a_table
WHERE
A like B AND
C like D)
```

Another note, this is of course an example query.  The real one has 5+ "where's" and 5+ "where not's". in case that makes any difference.

Is there a huge difference in efficiency/time/processing between these two methods?  I was always taught that the "like" function was bad and I should feel bad for using it, and by nature I would like to avoid it if I can.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: why don't you use `EXPLAIN` or similar to check on your database?

Comment: Most RDBMSs allow you to examine the execution plan of the query to examine the cost involved.  Find out how to do that with your RDBMS and compare both queries.

Comment: @sstan is it potentially different per-query?  I was hoping for not only an answer to this but something to use going forward should a similar situation arise, so I want to make sure any answer I decide upon is ok for more than just this instance.

Comment: Depending on the data (i.e. multiple rows per `someId`) the `NOT IN` might return a different result set. And n most cases a single pass over a table will be more efficient than two (outer SELECT and subquery)